# Lightview: a link to full sized photo instead of image title

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I like Lightview photo gallery script.
I use resized photos that i keep in "medium" folder which i want to let Lightview display when thumbnails are clicked, but i also have the full sized versions of the photos - original photos, which are 2000-3000 pixels wide/high that i need to give a way of viewing for people who'll want that.
So, instead of having image titles shown, i would like to show the following link "Click here to see full size photo" that would open a full sized photo in new window or the same window (skipping the lightview auto resize). I was thinking that it should be possible by altering some code or so, but i'm not much into writing code myself, i just could tweak it, with the help of community...

Could anyone help me and tell me what do do to have this functionality working?
I thought that maybe inside of a title description of the `<a>` tags i could put a path to the original photo, like `<a title="path/to/image.jpg">` but how do i do the rest?

To imagine what i'm talking about, please visit http://nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/ and click on the first photo on the left photo (yellow/red flower on blue bg) and then locate the "Move your mouse over the image to navigate." text, so i want to get rid of it and instead have a link to full size photos.

Thanks in advance for all the folks willing to help.
And Happy New Year!!!